# For the most part/Mostly

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

A: I work as a teacher.

B: You good at it?

A: I do okay, for the most part/mostly.

Questions:

1. Is "I do okay" natural here?
2. Is "for the most part" and "mostly" interchangeable here? Which is the more natural choice according to you?

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems fine!
2. I would say
   "I do okay, for the most part!"
   or
   "I do mostly okay"